# How do I split dates in the form of "Dec. 9, 2016" into three separate columns "12" "09" "2016" in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of dates in the format of Mmm. dd, yyyy that I'm trying to split into three separate columns, ones for day, month, and year.

I've tried the DATEVALUE function but it tells me that my input is in an improper format.

Comment: Use the `DAY`, `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions.

Comment: You may want to read this article to find out why your DATEVALUE formula failed: [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Using formula**

If your original date is always in the described structure, such as "**Dec. 9, 2016**", "**Jan. 31, 2018**", or "**Jun. 25, 2017**", then you can use excel formulas to find YEAR, DAY, and MONTH consecutively.

[image: Solution 1]

Here are the formulas:

To find YEAR: `=--RIGHT(A2,4)`

To find DAY: `=--TRIM(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-7-MOD(LEN(A2),12),LEN(A2)-10))`

To find MONTH: `=MONTH(DATEVALUE(D2&"-"&LEFT(A2,3)&"-"&B2))`

**Solution 2 - Using Power Query**

Alternatively, you can use **Power Query** to automatically recognize your original data as dates and split them into three columns as desired. See below steps:

[image: Solution 2]

Please note you need to have **Excel 2010 or later versions** to be able to use Power Query Editor.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

So say you have `Jan. 9, 2016`

1. Highlight the column
2. Go to the `Data Tab`
3. Click on `Text to Columns`
4. Follow the instructions

I have provided examples below, but im on my mac. It should look similar on windows and the process is the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Hope this helps